# query runs in sql server studio but not when called via python pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a query that I can successfully run in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio app. It outputs data as I expected.

However, when I try to run the script via Python, it'll always throw an error.

I first created a generic sql reader function:

```
def sql_reader_single(qry_file, server_name, database):
    server = db.connect(str('DRIVER={SQL Server};
                        SERVER='+server_name+';
                        DATABASE='+database+';'))
    qry = open(qry_file, 'r').read()
    data = pd.read_sql(qry, server)

return data
```

then I tried calling the above function to read my sql script:

```
dir = 'C:/Users/Documents/qry'
QryFile = os.path.join(dir, 'qry clean no comment.sql')
Data = sp.sql_reader_single(qry_file=QryFile, server_name='server1', database='db2')
```

And when I call the read.sql() function, I'd always get the following error:

```
 ': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'l'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

*'1' is the last character in my query script.* 
So the error message is saying I have syntax error near the last character of my script.

Since the query does run successfully in SQL server studio, that eliminates the hypothesis that my query is in wrong syntax, which is what the error message suggests.

Here's a sample query that I tried running but would get the above error code:

```
SELECT  distinct 
                      [ShipmentId]
                     ,shipmentstatus
                  FROM shipmentstatus
```

I also looked into many other links via Google search, but I am not getting any helpful tips. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's an "L" not a "1"

Comment: Without the query we can't really figure out why the L is a problem though

Comment: Maybe it's an encoding issue with your file?

Comment: Does your query statement have a ; at the end?  SQL Server doesn't require it but when run from python as a file it might.  You should add the actual query file contents

Comment: Hi all; I feel like whether it's an L or 1 shouldn't matter right? :( because it does run in sql server so the actual query syntax shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @indiri I tried with ";" but it's having the same error...

Comment: @StephenLightcap what do you mean by that? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Need the actual query to help here

Comment: @user8834780 hi, thanks for trying to help! but may i understand why the query must be shared? since the query does run, that means the problem is not within the query, right?

Comment: Nope, ODBC acts differently then sql server studio- there are a bunch of bugs such as necessity to quote reserved keywords that pyodbc has, which sql server is able to avoid

Comment: The two different environments can have different requirements. Before posting the query you can change table names and columns if that concerns you but do not change any punctuation so we can accurately see the issue.  The more you leave the better, though, as the column names may be the issue if they are reserved words as the person before me said.

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me! I see... I'll add one sample query now :)

Comment: @user8834780 and indiri Thank you for the expalanation! I've added some sample queries that I used but got the above error code with. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please post the **exact** query you are attempting. The *sample query* you posted cannot have raised that specific error which emphasizes the character `l`.