# random character added to my query when called from python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to call the following short script via python pyodbc (this is the content in my sql file):

```
SELECT distinct ShipmentId, shipmentstatus
    FROM log_shipmentstatus
```

I first created a generic sql reader function:

```
def sql_reader_single(qry_file, server_name, database):
    server = db.connect(str('DRIVER={SQL Server};
                        SERVER='+server_name+';
                        DATABASE='+database+';'))
    qry = open(qry_file, 'r').read()
    data = pd.read_sql(qry, server)

return data
```

then I tried calling the above function to read my sql script:

```
dir = 'C:/Users/Documents/qry'
QryFile = os.path.join(dir, 'qry clean no comment.sql')
Data = sp.sql_reader_single(qry_file=QryFile, server_name='server1', database='db2')
```

And when I call the read.sql() function, I'd always get the following error:

```
     pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'ÿþS E L E C T   d i s t i n c t    S h i p m e n t I d ,   s h i p m e n t s t a t u s 

   F R O M   l o g _ s h i p m e n t s t a t u s 

 ': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'L'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Notice how there are two random none alpha-numeric characters being added to the beginning of my query. How can I get rid of them?

I've checked the default system encoding type:

```
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
```

and I got "utf-8".

From waht I'm reading on Google, I should be using utf-8. Correct? I am very clueless right now...

Comment: Just because your systems default encoding is UTF-8, or the document CLAIMS to be UTF-8 doesnt mean it actually is. I would throw it into an editor which can swap between encodings or possibly even hexidecimal (sublime text can do that) and see what those leading characters or bytes (in the case of hex) actually are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [query runs in sql server studio but not when called via python pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086032/query-runs-in-sql-server-studio-but-not-when-called-via-python-pyodbc)

Comment: Don't ask the same question multiple times please.

Comment: @Xedni I am trying with Sublime but it doesnt let me change to hexidecimal... saying that "not all characters can be represented in hexidecimal so falling back to UTF-8"

Comment: Hex might be overkill anyway. UsuallyI can get the answer I need by going to File > Reopen with Encoding and swapping back and forth between UTF-8 and Windows 1252 (if the open is grayed out, you just have to save your file first). Then copy/paste whatever looks wonky into something like this: http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not random characters. 0xFF 0xFE is the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for UTF16 encoded data. The presence of these bytes indicates the encoding and endianess of the file/stream, in this case it is little endian UTF16. The additional "spaces" between the characters is also a hint: these are actually NUL characters (0x00) that have been rendered as spaces in the error message.

The solution is to re-encode the SQL script file to UTF8, ASCII or other supported encoding. You could do that to the file itself using a conversion tool such as `iconv` or open the file in an editor and save it back as UTF8.

Alternatively you can handle the encoding in your code. The nature of the problem suggests that you are using Python 2:

```
import codecs

def sql_reader_single(qry_file, encoding='utf16', server_name, database):
    server = db.connect(str('DRIVER={SQL Server};
                        SERVER='+server_name+';
                        DATABASE='+database+';'))

    with codecs.open(qry_file, encoding=encoding) as qf:
        data = pd.read_sql(qf.read(), server)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH @mhwake! but in your code, i only see you specified the encoding as utf16; but in your text, you said the solution is to reencode to UTF8. I am confused here, can you explain this part to me again?

Comment: If the file is in UTF16 and you open it with that encoding, it will be read correctly when it is needed, hence the UTF16

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions: re-encoding is the solution if you want to solve the problem by altering the SQL script file, but not the code. However, if you want to implement a code based solution (e.g. you can not change the SQL files), it is not necessary to re-encode because opening them with the required encoding will result in unicode strings being used, and the `pyodbc` module happily accepts them.

Comment: Thank you Erik and @mhawke! i understand now. Really appreciate your help! Cheers.